# BroadcastReceiver Not Working When App is removed from recent app list

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a Class "ConnectivityChangeReceiver" Class which extends BroadCastReceiver:

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intentPostTelemetry = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), PostTelemetryData.class);
    intentPostTelemetry.putExtra("isNetworkConnected", isConnected(context));
    context.startService(intentPostTelemetry);
}

public boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

}

This ConnectivityChangeReceiver class calls PostTemetryData

```
public class PostTelemetryData extends IntentService {

public PostTelemetryData() {
    super("PostTelemetryData");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    boolean isNetworkConnected = extras.getBoolean("isNetworkConnected");
    if (isNetworkConnected == true) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TelemetryInfo", 0);
        String telemetryDetailsInfo = sharedPreferences.getString("TelemetryDetailsInfo", null);
        if (telemetryDetailsInfo != null && !telemetryDetailsInfo.isEmpty()) {
            saveTelemetryData(telemetryDetailsInfo);
        }
    }
    // your code

}}
```

And in manifest i add following codes:

```
 <receiver android:name=".ConnectivityChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".PostTelemetryData"/>
```

This Broad Cast Receiver starts when connectivity changed.
Everything is working fine when the app is running.But When the app is closed and removed from the recent app list Then The Broadcast Receiver is not working So i can not save Data. So please help me out from this situation.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that your device is going to sleep after onReceive() is done, hence your IntentService is not getting to do its thing.

Try using this - https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

More simply, we acquire WakeLock in the onReceive() method of BroadcastReceiver, then start the service and release the wakelock in the onHandleIntent() method of IntentService.

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You really cannot do what you are trying to do. There is no way to keep your application running forever, and you can only catch `ACTION_BATTERY_*` where your app is running.